# PBEWithSHA1AndTripleDES vs PBEWithSHA1And3KeyTripleDES

Tags: java, encryption, jce

What's the difference of PBEWithSHA1AndTripleDES  and PBEWithSHA1And3KeyTripleDES, what does the 3key means there ?

All these 2 supported in IBM JCE as shown in below link

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_9.0.0/com.ibm.java.multiplatform.90.doc/user/compsec_jce_algos.html

Comment: Without any context this is a poor question. Neither algorithm appears in  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general '3-key' and '2-key' (aka triple-length and double-length key) are [keying options 1 and 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) of the cipher commonly called Triple-DES or 3DES or TDES or DES-EDE, although it was officially defined as TDEA. (In Java crypto, DES-EDE is customarily spelled with no hyphen and second part lowercase = DESede -- although case is ignored when algorithms are looked up by `Cipher.getInstance()` and similar.) This applies in both password-based encryption as here, and regular (key-based) encryption.

The mappings in the table clearly show that IBM implements the two schemes of password-based encryption (for private keys) using 3DES with these two keying options, defined by [PKCS12 aka rfc7292 in appendix C](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#appendix-C):

```
pbeWithSHAAnd3-KeyTripleDES-CBC  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {pkcs-12PbeIds 3}
pbeWithSHAAnd2-KeyTripleDES-CBC  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {pkcs-12PbeIds 4}
```

IBM provides several spellings of each name (with `-CBC` omitted) and for the 3-key scheme also the names with keying NOT specified `PBEWith{SHA-1,SHA1,SHA}And{3DES,DESede,TripleDES}` *and* the OID (which is usually more helpful for interchange) `{,OID.}1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3` as synonyms. This may be intended to ease transition from the Oracle-was-Sun-and-OpenJDK implementation, which implements *only* the 3-key scheme with the tweaked and abbreviated name `PBEWithSHA1AndDESede` and the OID as a synonym (the latter not documented AFAICS).

OTOH IBM apparently implements the four other PKCS12 schemes, based on RC2 and RC4, using the standard spellings plus variants `PBEWith{SHA,SHA-1,SHA1}And{40,128}Bit{RC2-CBC,RC4}` (and no OIDs?) whereas Oracle-and-OpenJDK 8+ uses `PBEWithSHA1AND{RC2,RC4}_{40,128}` and the corresponding OIDs. Go figure.

Comment: thanks . so in a word , PBEWithSHAAndTripleDES is keying option 1 , and PBEWithSHA1And3KeyTripleDES is keying option 3  ?

Comment: @JammyLee: no. The option numbers go in reverse of strength: option 1 is 3-key, option 2 is 2-key, option 3 is 1-key (which is basically useless because it is the same as original NON-triple DES/DEA). The names specifying 3key are option 1, triple length. The names not specifying key length are synonyms of 3key and thus the same option. The names specifying 2key are option 2, double length.